# How to trigger onchange event on dependent dropdowns when filling out web form using javascript

Tags: javascript, automation, webforms

I'm trying to automate the process of filling out lots of times a web form using the console in chrome with javascript. So far, I know how to assign a value to a text field or a drop down selection field, such as this:

```
document.getElementById('naam_werkgever_ld').value = 'Test';
```

Dropdowns are easily selected by using something like this:

```
function setSelectedIndex(s, v) 
{for (var i = 0; i < s.options.length; i++) 
    {if (s.options[i].text == v) 
        {s.options[i].selected = true;return;}
    }
}
setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById("test1"), "test2");
```

However, I'm having trouble when there are dependant fields, for example, if "dropdown1" is where "country" is selected, some onchange event must be triggered in order to show "states" in <>. How could I trigger all events after selecting an option without leaving the chrome console?

Comment: Why don't you do that from the backend bro? If the Dropdownlists are asp controls (runat = "server") you could use a "SelectedIndexChanged" event so that you change the value of the Dropdownlist you want.

Comment: Not feasible, wince Im not the developer of the platform, Im trying to automate filling a third party form.

Comment: I understand friend, that means that when you select a value of the "Country" Dropdownlist using the mouse it automatically changes the value of another Dropdownlist, but when you do it through JavaScript (Console) it doesn't work, is that so?